# Update JSONArray element usinh HttpUrlConnection PUT in java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Sample JSON is as below:

```
{
  "field1":9,
  "field2":[{\"key\":\"day\",\"value\":"Monday"},{\"key\":"month",\"value\":\"January\"}]
}
```

I am trying to update JSON field value using below code.

```java
String POST_PARAMS = "field1=10";//working fine
//String POST_PARAMS2 = "field2={"key":"day","value":"Tuesday"}"; return 400 code in PUT action
URL obj = new URL("https://someurl");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Above code works but when I try to update `field2` value using `POST_PARAMS2`. It returns me http response code 400. I want to update day value from Monday to Tuesday using `POST_PARAMS2` commented above.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: 400 is bad request , Check server Logs for the detailed error, It may be a logic that u may have used.

Comment: Consider reading response which server sends to you. It should contain details about what exactly is wrong.